# Erro ao compilar programa com biblioteca cURL em C++

Tags: c++, compiladores

Olá, sou iniciante no C++. Minha missão é incluir com sucesso a biblioteca cURL, de **forma estática sem DLL (o código deve ser incluso no .exe)**. Após muita pesquisa, tentativa e frustração compilando no Visual Studio 2019, decidi utilizar o compilador c++ para windows, no linux, fazendo o processo manualmente para tentar entender o erro que se repete.

**Código que tento compilar (arquivo main.cpp):**

```
#include "curl/curl.h"

int main(){
    // Inicia o cURL
    CURL* curl;
    curl = curl_easy_init();

    return 0;
}
```

**Comando que uso para compilar (no Linux):**

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -DCURL_STATICLIB -Ilibs/curl/include -Llibs/curl/lib -l libcurl_a main.cpp -o main.exe
```

**Erro ao compilar:**

```
/tmp/cc1qyBYq.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'
```

**Estrutura de arquivos do projeto (comodidade):**

```
projeto/
  -main.cpp
  -libs/
    -curl/
      -include/curl/<todos os header files>
      -lib/libcurl_a.lib
```

**OBS:** Já tentei de diversas formas essa compilação no Windows também.

**Como compilei a biblioteca cURL (em uma máquina Windows):**

1. Baixei do site oficial ([curl](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html));
2. Utilizei o *Developer Command Prompt* do VS para fazer a
   compilação. `nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static`.
3. No diretório builds, foi gerada a pasta `libcurl-vc-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl`, onde estão contidos `include/` e `lib/`.
4. Transferi os arquivos para o diretório do projeto (na máquina Linux), organizado da forma que apresentei acima.

---

Já pesquisei bastante a respeito, de acordo com o que entendi:

- Compilei os arquivos da biblioteca cURL;
- Informei ao compilador e aos arquivos headers do cURL que estou utilizando a biblioteca estática (`-DCURL_STATICLIB`)
- Importei o diretório dos arquivos header (`-Ilibs/curl/include`)
- Importei o diretório da biblioteca (`-Llibs/curl/lib`)
- Importei a biblioteca (`-l libcurl_a`)

---

É bem frustrante, pois fiz diversas tentativas e não tenho sucesso. Por favor ajudem, acredito que seja um erro recorrente, também, para outros iniciantes na linguagem. Grato desde já.

---

**Rodando o comando em modo verbose:**

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -DCURL_STATICLIB -Ilibs/curl/include -Llibs/curl/lib -l libcurl_a main.cpp -o main.exe -v


[Código anterior não mostrado por, aparentemente, não ter relevância]

GNU C++14 (GCC) version 7.3-win32 20180312 (i686-w64-mingw32)
compiled by GNU C version 7.3.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 4.0.1, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.19-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: d199463242a5239abcb58b29395ecf5b
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-static-libgcc' '-D' 'CURL_STATICLIB' '-I' 'libs/curl/include' '-Llibs/curl/lib' '-o' 'main.exe' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=pentiumpro'
 /usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-as -v -I libs/curl/include -o /tmp/cck4iQxU.o /tmp/ccWzC4RY.s
GNU assembler version 2.30 (i686-w64-mingw32) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.30
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3-win32/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3-win32/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3-win32/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3-win32/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3-win32/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3-win32/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3-win32/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-static-libgcc' '-D' 'CURL_STATICLIB' '-I' 'libs/curl/include' '-Llibs/curl/lib' '-o' 'main.exe' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=pentiumpro'
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3-win32/collect2 -m i386pe -Bdynamic -o main.exe /usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3-win32/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o /usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3-win32/crtbegin.o -Llibs/curl/lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3-win32 -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3-win32/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3-win32/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib -llibcurl_a /tmp/cck4iQxU.o -Bstatic -lstdc++ -Bdynamic -lmingw32 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmingw32 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt /usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3-win32/crtend.o
/tmp/cck4iQxU.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Seria legal tentar diretamente pelo prompt e acrescentar o log na postagem

Comment: @Bacco Não sei foi isso que você pediu.